# What is the difference between id and js-.. for js apeel in css?

Tags: javascript, css

This question relates to the article http://davidwalsh.name/css-do .
What are the differences and advantages these approaches?

```
<div class="do-launch-login">...</div>

<a class="do-close-modal">...</a>

<input class="do-autocomplete" />
```

and

```
<div id ="login" class="launch-login">...</div>

<a id="close" class="close-modal">...</a>

<input id="autocomplete" class="clautocomplete" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The author calls them `do-` prefixes, i call them (and use them as) `js-` or `jQ-` prefixes.
Javascript has a whole scale of possible applications in DOM manipulation... than just a *`do-`*  
 Those prefixes are to indicate **classes used exclusively by JS**, means you cannot find them in i.e: `style.css` but rather as part of some Javascript logic in `script.js`. 
 
Also **you cannot use ID multiple times** cause ID should be **unique-per-page**, so, classes in any case, spiced with a prefix to distinguish it's application.
(hm...`do-`... still seems pretty funny.)

Answer (score 0):

Personally for me, I generate a lot of dynamic HTML on the fly for my web applications. Because of this, I try to never use IDs as I make multiple instances of the same HTML objects.

It is considered terrible practice to ever have a duplicate of an ID, so I always use class names as selectors.

But that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Id should only be used for a single thing. However a class can be given to many different things.
You could easily google this for more in depth answer

Answer (score 0):

Some consider use of id in css a bad practice, because of:

> 1. The element is not re-usable on that page.
> 2. This is the beginning downward sprial into specificity.
> 3. Usually, IDs refer to something specific, and abstracting would be tough.
> 4. Any performance gains picked up by using id, is negated by adding any other selector to the left for that id

quoted from [http://screwlewse.com/](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/)